# Provisioning AWS Ubuntu using Ansible errors out with permission errors when gathering facts or installing apps regardless of become escalations

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ansible

When provisioning an AWS instance running `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-1028-aws x86_64)` provisioning stops at the following tasks:

`TASK [Gathering Facts]` task when `become:true` is set in the playbook. The following error message is displayed: `Missing sudo password`

`apt: update_cache=yes` task when `become: true` is set in the playbook and `gather_facts: false`. The following error message is displayed: `Missing sudo password`

`apt: update_cache=yes` task when `become: true` is `not` set in the playbook. The following error message is displayed: `Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation: Failed to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/: E:Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)"`

`TASK [geerlingguy.pip : Ensure Pip is installed.]`  task when `become: true` is `not` set in the playbook. The following error messages are displayed:
`"E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)",`
`"E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?"`

I suspect this is happening because this is a AWS modified OS, being `GNU/Linux 5.11.0-1028-aws`. I can ssh into the instance and run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install python3-pip` and it works without a password because I have `ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` set in `sudoers` for my ssh user. However, when I run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install python3-pip` with `become: true` is `not` set in the playbook, the above error messages are displayed.

I have run all versions of these and re-ran the playbook.

```sh
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
```

I found this stack overflow answer [Ansible playbook fails to lock apt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269225/ansible-playbook-fails-to-lock-apt/51919678#51919678) and added those tasks but it would fail at this step `raw: apt-get -y purge unattended-upgrades`.
`unattended-upgrades` seems to be disabled because I no longer see this message when I login to the instance.
`2 updates could not be installed automatically. For more details, see /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`

This is the first time I have had an issue with running these very basic ansible tasks. Given that AWS has its own ansible modules, I am sure I am doing something wrong or missing something obvious. I've had a hard time finding a solution to this problem because Googling has been ineffective. There are too many irrelevant results due to the popularity of the AWS ansible modules. I'm not trying to create or modify any AWS instances. I'm just trying to provision one.

I'm hoping one of the many AWS or Ansible experts here can help me out.

Here's the code: https://github.com/kahunacoder/ansible-wikijs

Here's an example

playbook.yml:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    pip_package: python3-pip
    pip_install_packages:
      - name: docker
  tasks:
    - name: Update apt
      apt: update_cache=yes
  roles:
    - geerlingguy.pip
```

hosts.yml:

```yaml
ansible_host: wiki.mydomain.com # dev machine
ansible_ssh_user: wiki
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
ansible_connection: ssh
ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

sudoers:

```sh
wiki ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: The issue is the fact that the user you are logging with (so your `remote_user` does have a password to use `sudo` but you fail to provide it. You can provide it with `--ask-become-pass` when running the playbook.

Comment: You should also check that you didn't mess with the `become_user`, as `become: true` is not forced to become `root` it can elevate you to any user provided by `become_user`.

Comment: I have `ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` set in `sudoers` for my ssh user

Comment: All this said, and because you are not providing us with any playbook or the relevant excerpt of an inventory make it something there is no chance someone can reproduce. Please read about [mre].

Comment: https://github.com/kahunacoder/ansible-wikijs

Comment: I've also tried `become_user` as well.

Comment: Regarding the repo link, you should read the ***minimal*** chapter of the page [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The fix was two lines of code to my ansible.cfg file.

```
[sudo_become_plugin]
flags = -H -S
```

I found the answer here: [Ansible: sudo without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434598/ansible-sudo-without-password)